# gitolite add repo specific post-receive hook

Tags: git, gitolite

I am trying to add a post-receive hook for specific repositories using this doc: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/cookbook.html

In my gitolite-admin repo I added `local/hooks/repo-specific/deploy` (which as of now just trys to touch a file) and added the line `option hook.post-receive = deploy` in `conf/gitolite.conf`.

On my server I looked up .gitolite.rc which initially didn't contain a *%RC block*.
So I tried to just add one to it:

```
%RC = (
    ENABLE => ['repo-specific-hooks'],
    LOCAL_CODE =>  "$rc{GL_ADMIN_BASE}/local"
);
```

After pushing changes to the repo with the hook I receive this error:

```
remote:                 ***** ABORTING *****
remote:         can't make head or tail of 'option hook.post-receive = deploy'
```

This is the first time I am using gitolite, so I might very well be missing something obvious. Anybody any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Gitolite V2.x. Repo-specific hooks are only supported since V3.6.

Are you using Debian? Then, you probably installed the `gitolite` package from apt. This is not what you want. Version 3 is (at least for Debian, Ubuntu and the like) installed with package `gitolite3`.

This is because V3 is not strictly compatible with V2. If you need to upgrade Gitolite, there is a tutorial at http://gitolite.com/gitolite/migr.html.

Comment: I am in awe of your detective skills :D

Comment: @dave Wasn't that hard. I grepped in Gitolite source code for that error message and found out that it was only in V2.x. For the Debian part, well... To be honest, I made that same mistake a few weeks ago, too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The `RC` section of [`src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L501`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/f480dbf9275b7a82ccbff208f2925a25864432b9/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L501) is actually the content of `.gitolite.rc`.

Meaning you should not add a `%RC` section, but directly those entries.

[As documented](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/rc.html):

> You can always get a default copy for your current version by running `gitolite print-default-rc`.